# Crash with a x64 .NET 4.0 application in Release mode outside of the IDE only

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, pinvoke, windows-7-x64

So, I'm experiencing a very weird issue with my little test application. And by issue, I mean it crashes... hard. No exception (at least, nothing that I could catch) is thrown, just the "Blah Blah has stopped responding..." message. It crashes ***ONLY*** when I run the app in **x64, release mode and outside of the IDE**.  If I run it in x86 mode, or if I run it in the IDE in x64 or I run it standalone as DEBUG in x64 it works fine.

I've narrowed it down to my p/invoke PeekMessage call. So, I need the brilliant minds here to look at the crap I've written and tell me if I'm doing it right. Because, seriously, I'm about to lose my f**king mind. I've tried this on 2 computers and they both exhibit the same behaviour. I'm a little concerned that this could be a .NET 4.0 bug.

Anyway, here's my p/invoke code. Please let me know if you see anything odd or just plain stupid:

Here's the call to PeekMessage:

```
private static bool PeekMessage()
{
        MSG message = new MSG();                // Message to retrieve.

        return Win32API.PeekMessage(ref message, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, PeekMessageFlags.NoRemove);
}
```

Here's PeekMessage (NOTE: The suppress security attribute is on the class definition, so it is being applied):

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool PeekMessage(ref MSG msg, IntPtr hwnd, uint wFilterMin, uint wFilterMax, PeekMessageFlags flags);
```

Here's the MSG:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct MSG
{
        /// <summary>Window handle.</summary>
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        /// <summary>Message to process.</summary>
        public uint Message;
        /// <summary>Window message parameter 1.</summary>
        public uint wParam;
        /// <summary>Window message parameter 2.</summary>
        public uint lParam;
        /// <summary>Time message was sent?</summary>
        public uint time;
        /// <summary>Mouse pointer position.</summary>
        public Point pt;
}
```

And finally, the PeekMessageFlags:

```
internal enum PeekMessageFlags
{
        /// <summary>Keep message on the message queue.</summary>
        NoRemove = 0,
        /// <summary>Remove message from the queue.</summary>
        Remove = 1,
        /// <summary>Do not yield execution to waiting threads.</summary>
        NoYield = 2
}
```

I checked the event log and I got this:

```
Faulting application name: Tester_Graphics.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4ec0ba85
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000001cb
Faulting process id: 0x1260
Faulting application start time: 0x01cca299e2c21a77
Faulting application path: D:\Code\Current\Gorgon\Branches\2.x\Dorian\Examples\Tester_Graphics\bin\Release\Tester_Graphics.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 20ac891f-0e8d-11e1-a5d7-bcaec5753ddd
```

So, if you see anything not quite right, please let me know. I'd hate for this to not be my fault.

Sorry if it's not detailed enough, if you need more info, just leave a note.

Comment: I had similar issues with even the slightest wrong parameters, especially strings (Unicode vs. Ansi etc.) [This page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.peekmessage) lists a different signature for `PeekMessage`. I suggest you try several others until you find one the works.

Comment: As a random note, if you were having trouble debugging this that it caused the exception. Assuming you could load your program after you built it, you could run it. Then usual visual studio attach to process and you should be able to debug it even in release mode as long as the PDBs are with it. Then you could turn on break on any thrown exception (CTRL+ALT+E) and you probably would've gotten alot more information.

Comment: Yeah, I considered doing that, but it exceptioned right away, so there was no time to attach.  I realize now that I could have added a `Sleep` delay before the `PeekMessage`, but it was midnight and I was barely able to form coherent sentences, so it didn't occur to me at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of `lParam` and `wParam` fields of `MSG` are wrong.  You should use `IntPtr` instead of `uint` / `int`.

If you take a look at [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can see that:

- `LPARAM` is a `LONG_PTR` i.e. its 32 bits in size of 32 bit platforms and 64 bits in size on 64 bit platforms.
- `PARAM` is a `UINT_PTR` which again is 32 bits in size of 32 bit platforms and 64 bits in size on 64 bit platforms.

Conversely the `int` and `uint` types are both 32 bits in size *regardless of the platform*, meaning that on 64 bit platforms your `MSG` struct is 64 bits too small which will result in some sort of memory corruption.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw this after Uwe Keim suggested I visit pinvoke.net.  I had done that last night.  I changed it to `IntPtr` and it worked like a charm.  So thank you to both of you.